# Android GridView click not being detected

Tags: android, gridview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have the following `LinearLayout` with a `GridView` in it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/songs_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:columnWidth="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `GridView` data is supplied by a custom adapter (using a simple `ViewHolder`):

```
public class SongsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private ArrayList<Song> songList;

    public SongsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Song> songList)
    {
        this.context = context;

        this.songList = songList;

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return songList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return songList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        SongViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.song_list_item, null);

            viewHolder = new SongViewHolder();

            //Get Views from Layout Template
            viewHolder.AlbumArt = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.albumart);
            viewHolder.Title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.Artist = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (SongViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Song song = songList.get(position);

        Bitmap bitmap = song.getAlbumArt();
        Bitmap missing = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.albumart_missing);

        Bitmap albumArt = bitmap == null ? missing  : bitmap;

        viewHolder.AlbumArt.setImageBitmap(albumArt);
        viewHolder.Title.setText(song.getTitle());
        viewHolder.Artist.setText(song.getArtist());

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

When the app starts it gets a list of songs (from xml but currently using a manually entered list) and passes that to the my adapter and then sets the `OnItemClickListener`:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.songs_grid);
gridView.setAdapter(new SongsAdapter(this, fk.getSongList()));

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view;

        TextView songTitle = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.song_title);

        Song song = fk.getSong((String) songTitle.getText());

        if(song != null)
        {
            Intent play = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Play.class);
            startActivity(play);
        }
    }
});
```

When I first implemented this code, it all worked fine, and I am sure I haven't changed anything. I was trying to make the text for Song Title scroll in a marquee fashion if it was too long, but couldn't get it working. During this phase I discovered that the click stopped working. I have now removed (I believe) all that code, but it still fails.

When I touch/click (whatever you call it) nothing happens. no errors nothing.

Is there anything wrong with my code that would cause this issue?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, so I'll just post as a comment; Remove the clickable-attribute from the gridview. I think that this might override the click-events for the items in the view-

Comment: Try to add a log in order to check if onItemClick is called. If yes, check the value of songPackage.

Comment: @Jave sadly not, I believe I added that to try and get it working, but removing still didn't work! :( thanks though!

Comment: What about the song_list_item layout? Are any of its views marked as clickable? That might stop the grid's onclick from responding.

Comment: @DimitrisMakris confirmed with Debug & Log statement that the onItemClick is never called.

Comment: So you should the layout of the grid item as @dmon proposed and you can also try to set the onclicklistener before you set the adapter.

Comment: @dmon Full Marks to you! I looked over and over the list and never saw the one lingering in the LinearLayout! Such a little bug can cause so much frustration! Add as an Answer and I'll mark it

Comment: @Jave as you were close, I guess I could +1 yours as an answer too if you add it :)

Comment: Glad that helped, added as an answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check your item layout. If any of the song_list_item layout views are marked as clickable they will block the grid's onclick listener from responding.

Comment: This. A thousand times this. Clickable on the layout will override click-events for the gridview. Such a terrible way of handling click events.

Comment: I'm curious about how come this answer doesn't have a few million more upvotes.

Comment: I just tested and noticed that the `focusable` property also blocks the click-events for the gridview.

Comment: Wow, I've been searching for an answer to this for a while. Such a simple fix, thanks so much!

Comment: Applying a button style to a view will also set the clickable attribute to true and block click events.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the `clickable`-attribute in the GridView does not override the click-events for the items in the view.

Comment: This is completely accurate, and the same response as the 'correct answer'. Layout clickable-attributes completely eats the event from the GridView.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to ur cell xml

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and the solution is similar to dmon's answer. If one of the item's child is selectable, it also prevents the item to be clickable. So if the `android:textIsSelectable` is true.

Answer (score 1):

if you make all the image view and text view android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

There won't be any problem in gridview item click listener